# How to switch between Release and Debug config without regenerating the CMake cache and recompiling the entire project?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, compilation

I'm working on a C++ project with Visual Studio, and I often need to switch between Debug and Release. But every time I switch, CMake generates a new cache and I need to build the whole project, which takes quite some time.

Is there a way to compile both once, and then only rebuild the files I just modified?

Comment: How are you generating the build files? Visual studio manages this for you by default, do you mean visual studio code?

Comment: I configure the CMake cache and then compile and install the project

Comment: How do you do that? Are you generating visual studio projects with cmake then opening them? Opening the cmake folder in visual studio and getting it to do the generation? something else?

Comment: I open the folder containing my project with Visual Studio, where there is the main CMakeList.txt. Then I go Project -> Configure Cache.

Comment: By default this puts the build for each configuration in a separate folder, if you haven't changed that it will just work, if you have then change it back

Comment: It does put it in separate folders, but every time I change the configuration Visual Studio automatically generate CMake cache, and I need to recompile the project even if I haven't done any change.

Comment: Please show a [mre], that shouldn't happen

Answer (score 0):

## set debug flags for a single target by modifying makefile

Cmake generates a bunch of makefiles for each target. You could modify the target to have debug flags after you have already built it.

```bash
# build your project using regular release and optimization flags
cmake ..
make
# edit the flags used to build a particular target
vim CMakeFiles/mytarget.dir/flags.make
```

**Origional CMakeFiles/mytarget.dir/flags.make**

```
CXX_FLAGS = -Wall -funroll-loops -march=native -O3 -DNDEBUG   -pthread -std=gnu++17
```

> Your flags will be different and is project dependent.

**Modified CMakeFiles/mytarget.dir/flags.make**

```
CXX_FLAGS = -Wall -march=native -g -DNDEBUG   -pthread -std=gnu++17
```

> note `-g` instead of `-O3`

**rebuild and observe compiler arguments**

```bash
# make it rebuild my particular target
touch $PATH_TO_TARGET_MAIN
make VERBOSE=1 mytarget
```

> search the output for `-g`